# VirtualBox NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) macOS

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I'm using macOS and installed VirtualBox.

When I start a machine, I'm getting the following error :

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine ubuntu.

The virtual machine 'ubuntu' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {85cd948e-a71f-4289-281e-0ca7ad48cd89}
```

Comment: StackOverflow's scope is limited to questions about *writing code*, or tools exclusively for that use. Questions about usage/troubleshooting that doesn't involve modifying a program's source code are a better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), or a platform-specific Stack Exchange site such as [unix.se] or [apple.se].

Comment: This is now an issue on macOS 12.0.1 Monterey, too

Comment: @CharlesDuffy SuperUser only if this does turn out to be a permissions issue, which it is NOT on my instance.  Unix & Linux for a MacOSX-specific question? Nah.  
I have been through every answer in this thread and non seems to be the correct answer in my situation.  MacOSX Monterey, newest VBox version.

Comment: @DevlshOne, I'll grant you that [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [apple.se] is a better choice than [unix.se] (though MacOS X _is_ a UNIX) -- but the above doesn't make any kind of argument for keeping it here on Stack Overflow. Our scope is limited to questions about writing code or about tools that are specific to development work. VirtualBox isn't specific to development work, and there's no code in the question at all.

Comment: 2023 answer - first, just try upgrading VirtualBox to the most recent version.

Answer (score 95):

This error seems to appear with VirtualBox installs on versions of macOS 10.13.

To fix this issue, you have to uninstall VirtualBox (use the `VirtualBox_uninstall.tool` of the VirtualBox downloaded dmg).

Then, install it again executing `VirtualBox.pkg`. At the end of the install, go to System Preferences, Security and Privacy, and the click the `allow` button :

[image: Allow Oracle America, Inc.]

The preferences pane has changed in macOS Ventura. You have to find the corresponding section in `Privacy & Security` which has a button to configure the extensions and then asks fora restart.

[image: Ventura system extensions]

This should solve your issue.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", and the link therein to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: just uninstalling via the tool and then reinstall did the trick for me!

Comment: Also. If it doesn't work after this:
Uninstall Virtualbox
Open Security Preferences
Allow
Instal Virtualbox
Run Genymotion
Profit!l

Comment: I didn't even need to do a separate uninstall step... just installed the latest version and that fixed it.

Comment: I never had the option to allow developer "Oracle…". I'm basically stuck at this point.

Comment: I didn't need to reinstall VirtualBox, just clicked "allow" button in system preference :)

Comment: (Using macOS 11.4 Big Sur) Since I originally installed via Homebrew, I decided to try applying this answer via brew before resorting to a conventional download and install. The following worked for me: `csrutil status` (make sure it says "System Integrity Protection status: enabled.") Then `brew uninstall --cask virtualbox` and `brew install --cask virtualbox` folowed by a reboot to allow the kext to activate. All my previous vboxes were still listed and they worked. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: This worked for me on macOs 11.4 Big Sur, with VirtualBox 6.1

Comment: @BrunoBronosky I'm trying this with macOs 11.4 Big Sur & VirtualBox 6.1 but every time I visit system preferences in Security & Privacy I don't see the message about blocked software components.

I vaguely remember Mac saying something like that a long time ago but I don't know how to find it again...

Comment: @adejones Could you provide more info? I am on the same system but the fix is not working for me. I cannot see the allow button in security & privacy...

Comment: @profPlum I installed from the dmg downloaded from virtualbox.org rather than via homebrew. All I can suggest is you uninstall using VirtualBox_uninstall.tool in the dmg, then reboot and reinstall. The Security & Privacy General tab should show the system software that needs permission to run.

Comment: @profPlum ... then perhaps reboot again as it's dealing with a kernel extension.

Comment: Go to settings and privacy, And do this change. After a restart it works.

Comment: Doesn't solve my issue on Monterey.

Comment: for me macOs 11.3 Big sur. I installed virtualbox via homebrew. Uninstall it and install again doesn't trigger the prompt reappear in Security & Privacy.

Comment: For me on Ventura 13.3.1, just upgrading to VirtualBox 7.0.8 did the trick.

Answer (score 19):

Here is what worked for me.  I kept getting that error when I was trying to 'add' the ISO after clicking start on the VM to set it up.

However, when I clicked on 'Tools' on the left sidebar, then click "Media". From there I was able to add my Kali Linux ISO so when I started the VM again, the ISO showed up in the list.

[image: Screenshot of VirtualBox VM]

Answer (score 18):

- Download the virtualbox extension from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

[image]

- Run it and it works!

Comment: you save me m8.

Comment: @Vasilisck Glad to hear :)

Comment: Thanks! Helped! The version of VB and the pack has to match I guess.

Comment: The version of the extension pack has to be exactly the same as the version of VirtualBox.
You need to install it under File - Options - Extensionpack.

Comment: Didn't work, yay!

Comment: I am guessing this answer only helps if you have an outdated version of the Extension Pack?

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at this from a troubleshooting perspective. The number one thing to do instead of guessing is diagnose and the best way to do that when you don't know what the problem is. I'll take you through the steps for my particular use case but it should give you a general idea on how to look at the problem in order to find the correct solution.

a.-Have a look at the actual logs of the VM:

Click on the Menu Item, you should see three choices:

1. Details
2. Snapshots
3. Logs

Look for this error code:
VMSetError and look for the matching RETURN CODE (rc)
rc=VERR_VD_IMAGE_READ_ONLY

In the example below the file under /build/virtualbox....is in read only mode.

```
 VMSetError: /build/virtualbox-8vePuu/virtualbox-6.1.16-dfsg/src/VBox/Devices/Storage/DrvVD.cpp(5228) int drvvdConstruct(PPDMDRVINS, PCFGMNODE, uint32_t); rc=VERR_VD_IMAGE_READ_ONLY
```

b.-Interpret what that means:
But the problem is the /build directory does not exist at all. So what the rc above really means is that it cannot FIND that file, because /build doesn't even exist (nor it seems to be supposed to).

```
cd: /build/virtualbox-8vePuu/virtualbox-6.1.16-dfsg/src/VBox/Devices/Storage/: No such file or directory
root@pop-os:~# cd /build/virtualbox-8vePuu/virtualbox-6.1.16-dfsg/
-bash: cd: /build/virtualbox-8vePuu/virtualbox-6.1.16-dfsg/: No such file or directory
root@pop-os:~# cd /build
-bash: cd: /build: No such file or directory
root@pop-os:~# ls /
bin   dev  home  lib32  libx32      media  opt   root  sbin  sys  usr
boot  etc  lib   lib64  lost+found  mnt    proc  run   srv   tmp  var
```

Another thing to notice is that for my case other VMs with VDIs in the same location don't have the problem.
That completely discards two possibilities:

- There's a problem with the install of Virtual Box
- There's an actual file permissions issue

The possibility is that the VM got corrupted at some point during shut down and that created the config corruption, not a VDI corruption at the VM level, not VirtualBox level.

Unless you power off your VM the "Close" function on your Vm window will ALWAYS save the state of the machine, so "Discarding" the state is only possible when you have two or more states because in that case at a minimum there is always the LAST state.

The conclusion is then that the corruption is at the VM state level and we need to get rid of that.

c.-Solution:

Go to VM-> Menu->Snapshots -> Clone

Create a linked Clone. That will simply copy the config files to the right place and link with the same VDI.

Start that one.
If it starts you know you have a problem with the original VM. You can either re-create the VM and point to the existing VDI or create a full clone (it will take longer) and the delete the original.

To prevent this (at least for my case), avoid sending the Power Off Message to your VM when closing, better use the ACPI Shutdown method as Power off can leave (as we saw) your machine on an unwanted state.

Answer (score 4):

Using a readonly filesystem, blocking VBox files wrtiting access causes this error.
Move VBox virtual machines files to a new location with writing permissions must resolves this problem. In my case, i use a Linux server, with VBOx software but my machine was moved to a Windows partition with BitLocker active and the windows Disk was mounted in ReadOnly, causing this problem.

Answer (score 3):

If somebody have problem with run virtual machine after upgrade VirtualBox on BigSur 11.6.3, first should check System Extension in System preferences -> Security & Privacy and allow Run Oracle. After rebooting computer, virtual machine start normally.

Answer (score 3):

Same thing happened to me after upgrading to MacOS Ventura 13.1. I solved the issue by installing VirtualBox 7 from their website.
https://www.virtualbox.org

Answer (score 2):

I had the issue when I upgraded and I used the **Extensions** feature.

Check that your extensions have been updated as well.  Download the latest from VirtualBox Website.  Select File / Preferences and then the Extensions.  Click the add symbol and select the new updated extension file.

Try and restart your virtual machine again.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Thx @jonathan-homer, that was the solution that worked for me (because I had a missing / broken extension pack on my host, obviously)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue on Mac OS Big Sur 11.4 when I was trying to add my Ubuntu instance (on Intel tho), nothing suggested here and other topics helped. Turned out you have to give access (Full Disc Access) to Virtual Box in Settings. Go to Settings -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disc Access -> plus sign (unlock it if needed) -> choose Virtual Box Application -> Open. After that I was able to choose my Ubuntu image in Finder.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work

Comment: Didn't work for me, either.  Even after two uninstall / reinstalls and manually adding Oracle VBox to the Files and Folders Access role.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with the latest Monterey Macos. Just run the following commands on your terminal.

```
sudo kextload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv
sudo kextload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt
sudo kextload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp
sudo kextload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB
```

And here's where I got these commands from:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=104272&sid=617676a134b8f244304a58cbe41c3e86

[update] Unfortunately, I have to execute this command every time I restart my laptop. I'll put a definitive solution once I get it.

Comment: I get an error: Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=71 "Kernel request failed: (libkern/kext) kext (kmod) start/stop routine failed (-603946985)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Kernel request failed: (libkern/kext) kext (kmod) start/stop routine failed (-603946985)}

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue after I upgraded to Monterrey from Big Sur. To fix:

- completely uninstall Virtualbox. Do this by downloading and opening the DMG and choose 'Virtualbox_uninstall.tool'. You will get a permission denied error, so go to System Preferences->Security and Privacy->General tab, and click on the relevant 'Allow' in 'Allow apps downloaded from:' section. This will run the script
- install VirtualBox 6.1.30 (the latest will likely work as well). I still got  the same "NS_ERROR_FAILURE" error.  Again go to System Preferences->Security and Privacy->General tab and allow Oracle from the 'Allow apps downloaded from:' section. You will have to reboot

Answer (score 2):

macOS BIG Sur v 11.6:

this post is open for a long time but no solution worked for me but finally I found the solution

- start virtualbox with terminal in sudo mode

```
sudo virtualbox
```

- install your ova system kali, unbutu...
- start your vm after to have change the settings
- during the launch of your vm it is possible that macos must have allow your audio device click "allow"

I found this solution [forums.virtualbox](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=97141)

thanks to them

Comment: So, starting virtualbox as sudo did it for me. I installed Virtualbox with he dmg file but still launched with terminal. My windows partition wasn't visible so I simply dragged and dropped the .vbox file into the window and it was ready. After starting the SD card reader was there and I was even able to burn an Android image to it.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue with `vagrant version v2.3.2` and VirtualBox version `7.0.2` on `macOS Ventura`. In my case, the issue was solved by doing the following:

```
# 1
sudo su
csrutil clear

#2
Then uninstall VirtualBox using the official uninstaller after that reboot the system.

#3
After the reboot install VirtualBox again using:

brew install --cask virtualbox

#4 
Add this line to your Vagrantfile:
virtualbox__intnet: true

#5
vagrant up
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm running macOs Ventura. After getting this error, I simply downloaded and installed latest version of Virtualbox, it simply fixed this issue and run without any problems.

Comment: Same here but the key is to download and install VirtualBox 7. If you have VirtualBox 6.1 it doesn't work and checking for updates claim there is no update. You need to look for version 7, download it and install it. Beware.

Answer (score 2):

For me it happened after upgrading my MacOS to Ventura. I also had to upgrade my VB to 7.x as mentioned [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=107759) to fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

I got this when I was trying to restore a suspended session. The fix was to click the "Discard" button (down arrow icon) and just discard the saved machine state. It's at least faster that uninstall/reinstall, I'd try it first.

Comment: yes, discarding the saved state works.

Answer (score 1):

That file is obviously corrupted. If you go to that location [1], you'll see a 0-bytes file. In that same folder, chances are you're going to find a file named "VirtualBox.xml-prev". Delete the "VirtualBox.xml" file (the 0-bytes one) and rename the "VirtualBox.xml-prev" to "VirtualBox.xml".

If there is no "VirtualBox.xml-prev", or if it's also a 0-bytes file, then don't worry, it's still fixable. Just delete both of these files, they will be re-created when VirtualBox runs again. You simply would have lost any VirtualBox preferences and registered VMs that you might have had. Not the VMs themselves, the list of the VMs. You need to re-register your VMs, by either double-clicking on the .vbox file of every VM that you have, or go to the menu "Machine" » "Add" and navigate to the .vbox file of each of your existing VMs. Your VMs are located (by default) in "/Users//VirtualBox VMs".

Comment: Didn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on Vagrant and VirtualBox with the latest macOS Monterey, I will tell you based on my hour's search that it is the incompatible issue of the latest Monterey.

I now have several options to do. one is to downgrade to the last version of macOS(annoying), the other is to continually find a walk around.

you may find this to be useful as a walk around:

add code below in your vagrant file to start with GUI instead of headless

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run an OS with state saved, then right clicking the Virtual machine and pressing discard saved state could resolve the issue.

Comment: This was the only solution here that worked for me (Big Sur v11.1; VirtualBox v7.0.10). Obviously lost the saved state, but the machine was otherwise as I left it (i.e. like it had been turned off instead of hibernated).

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS Mojave, owner for /Applications folder needs to be user root, group admin. Same for the VirtualBox.app folder.
This was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issie, but root cause was completely different then other answers.

In my case it turn out that problem was configuration of the image. If you select VM image check its settings then you can see this:

[image]

Now if you hover mouse over warring triangle you  will get hint that some configuration setting is invalid. As you can see above I had some network adapter miss configured.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with MacOS Monterey 12.6.2 + Latest VirtualBox 7.0
I first uninstalled using official virtualbox uninstall tool
then re-installed and everything was working fine..